# Python arguments in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, arguments, python-3.4

For context, I have a function that is used to generate a button. The last two arguments of the function are used to fun another function when the button is pressed.

Im having problems with a button such as this, when Im trying to call the function (and arguments) createWorksheet(sheetTitle,sheetDate,sheetFilename) when the button is pressed.

I aimed to do it using this code:

```
button("Create Sheet",200,500,200,50,GREEN,BRIGHTGREEN,createWorksheet,sheetTitle,sheetDate,sheetFilename)
```

but this gives the error

```
button() takes from 7 to 9 positional arguments but 11 were given
```

Instead I tried with the arguments in a tuple (as below)

```
button("Create Sheet",200,500,200,50,GREEN,BRIGHTGREEN,createWorksheet,(sheetTitle,sheetDate,sheetFilename))
```

but this throws an error:

```
createWorksheet() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'date' and 'filename'
```

Any ideas please?

This is the button code to generate the function

```
def button(text, posX, posY, width, height, inactiveColor, activeColor,action=None,actionArgs=None):
    global buttonDown

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if posX + width > mouse[0] > posX and posY + height > mouse[1] > posY:

        pygame.draw.rect(displays, activeColor, (posX,posY, width, height))

        if click[0] == 1 and not buttonDown and action!= None:

            if actionArgs is not None:
                action(actionArgs)
            else:
                action()

            buttonDown = True

        elif click[0] == 0:
            buttonDown = False
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(displays,inactiveColor,(posX,posY,width,height))

    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(text, smallfont)
    textRect.center = ( (posX + (width/2)), (posY+(height/2)) )
    displays.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? I think what you want is a `lambda` or `functools.partial` that wraps `createWorksheet` and includes those additional parameters, but it's not clear why you thought you could pass them like that; it makes no sense.

Comment: `action(actionArgs)` is passing the tuple as a single argument instead of unpacking it.

Comment: @user2357112 How would I go about unpacking it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+unpack+arguments

Comment: @user2357112 The problem with me doing action(*actionArgs) is that is throwing an error for anything passed with a single argument. Thank you

Comment: You need to decide whether this thing takes a tuple of arguments, or just one. If you want to be able to pass a tuple for `actionArgs`, you need a 1-element tuple for 1 argument. (Note that `(1,)` is a 1-element tuple and `(1)` is just `1`.)

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you. Problem now fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the second invocation, i.e. using a tuple for the args, is correct. However you need to pass the arguments to the `action` function as positional arguments, not as a tuple.

You don't show the definition for `createWorksheet()` but assuming that it takes the 3 arguments from your example, you would call it like this:

```
        if actionArgs is not None:
            action(*actionArgs)
        else:
            action()
```

This *unpacks* the tuple into separate values, and passes these to the function. The difference is this:

```
args = (sheetTitle, sheetDate, sheetFilename)
action(args)    # passes a single argument of type tuple
```

vs.

```
action(*args)   # passes each element of the tuple as a positional argument.
```

The second case is the same as:

```
action(sheetTitle, sheetDate, sheetFilename)
```

If you have only one argument to pass, you still need to pass it as a one element tuple to `button()`, like this:

```
button("Create Sheet",200,500,200,50,GREEN,BRIGHTGREEN,createWorksheet,(sheetTitle,))
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem now fixed. I really appreciate it